# disable terminal werase setting only in interactive mode in bash

Tags: bash, readline, stty

I want to bind <kbd>C^w</kbd> to a non-default action in `bash`, but it requires disabling `werase` in the terminal. This, unfortunately, affects other programs launched by bash, especially my ssh sessions: when I type <kbd>C^w</kbd> there it echoes `^W`.

Is there a way to enable some non-default terminal setting only in interactive mode in bash and have it automatically disable/restore it when it runs commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a readline option to stop it taking up the current stty settings. Add to your `~/.inputrc`

```
set bind-tty-special-chars Off
```

then you will be able to bind <kbd>Control-w</kbd> as you wish.
Interactively, you can try:

```bsh
$ bind 'set bind-tty-special-chars Off'
$ bind -ps | grep C-w
"\C-w": unix-word-rubout
$ bind -x '"\C-w": date'
```

then typing the character runs the `date` command, but the stty settings are unaffected.